# python statsmodel WLS memory/gc "leak" at n=1024 boundary

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, statsmodels

I run jobs with loops that call statsmodels.api.WLS (version 0.6.1) several times per loop.  It appears that statsmodels refuses to give up memory despite my best attempts and ends up taking up all my memory (32Gb).  I wrote the following example code to demonstrate the problem.

The interesting thing is that there is no problem if the dimension of the problem is within 1024 (n =< 1024).  **However, if n >= 1025, then this script's memory usage increases linearly without bound**.  Looks like an error in statsmodel.api but it could be my poor understanding of python.

(cross-posted on: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2428)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import resource
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1025
    mu, sigma = 0.0, 1.0
    i = 0
    print('i,memory')
    while True:
        x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
        y = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
        w = np.random.random(n)
        w /= w.sum()
        regr1 = sm.WLS(y, x, w)
        print(`i` + ',' + `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss`)
        i+=1
```

The first 10 values of n=1024 and n=1025:

```
i   N_1024  N_1025
0   60680   60812
1   60680   60848
2   60816   60988
3   60816   60996
4   60816   61016
5   60816   61028
6   60816   61040
7   60816   61064
8   60816   61080
9   60816   61084
10  60816   61092
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to numpy 1.9.1 (from 1.7.1) and the problem automagically disappeared